# Detecting catcode in parameter text

Tags: tex-core

Say someone has defined

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

\def\fooA#1@{}
\makeatletter
\def\fooB#1@{}

\end{document}
```

It is easy to test and see that the two are different: `\ifx\fooA\fooB...\else...\fi`.

But if we are given one of `\fooA` and `\fooB` and we have not seen the definition before, can we tell what the catcode of the `@` delimiting the parameter is?

Disclaimer: I am interested in the answer out of sheer curiosity.

EDIT: basically, is there a version of `\meaning` which keeps catcodes? or is there a way to show the catcodes of tokens in the parameter text? --- The answer, below, is "no".

Comment: You might want to look at what `etoolbox` does, where it checks if the catcodes in a definition are at least the same as those which are current.

Comment: @Joseph: an interesting piece of code. etoolbox does not seem to have a documented source :(. --- For those interested, `\etb@ifscanable` does the following: it reads the meaning of its argument; splits it in the different pieces (prefixes, parameter text, replacement text) ; and builds a definition out of this. Then it compares the result of the definition with the original command using `\ifx`. If it is the same, then etoolbox knows that it can recreate the macro, and hence patch it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The only ways to read the definition of a macro (and its parameter text) is `\meaning` (`\show` only displays it to the user).
Unfortunately it turns all characters to the catcode "other", except spaces which stay spaces. Therefore you can not detect the difference.

Comment: Ok. I was afraid this would be the answer in general. What about ts special case? Maybe trying something like `...\foo...@...@...` with two different catcodes for `@` might work? or some more devious `\batchmode\foo@\errorstopmode` to check if `\foo` accepts its argument?

Comment: @Bruno: What exactly do you want to do? Test if the macro will expand correctly? Or defining one which will expand correctly independent from the current catcodes?

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess that the general question made sense, but the more specific one would only make sense with a specific application in mind. And as I said, I was only curious... And I cannot remember what made me think about this. Sorry for the hassle :).

Answer (score 3):

A disappointing answer: This has nothing to do with catcodes of `\fooA` or `\fooB`. The `\ifx` test just sees that the parameter texts of the two macros are different (they contain different `@`s), so it turns out negative. The `\ifx` test doesn't care *what* the difference is.

Comment: @Bruno, ups, you edited your code parallel to me writing my comment, so I deleted it again, because I thought it was not necessary any longer ...

Comment: @Bruno: My answer was not formulated well (it was the last thing before going to bed); I tried to make it clearer what I mean.

Comment: Now this makes sense. It doesn't quite answer my question, but that's because the question was unclear :).

Comment: I think that your first comment should remain. --- For the record, many comments were written and deleted on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Following the comments of Bruno and Joseph on the question, if you were willing to sacrifice speed (significantly), you could reconstruct the command a la `\etb@ifscanable` in `etoolbox` for every possible catcode combination of the tokens (characters?) in the parameter text, and see which one `\ifx`ed to the original command.

(I don't think you'd even be able to special case `#1`, etc., if you wanted it to catch `\bar` in something like

```
\def\gobblethree#1#2#3{}
\edef\foo{\def\noexpand\bar\expandafter\gobblethree\detokenize{##}1{}}
\foo
```

)

Comment: I thought about this, and indeed, it is possible in principle, but really... `;-)` An alternative perhaps would be to hook into the definition of `\def` (and `\edef`, `\gdef`, `\xdef`, `\afterassignment`, `\global`, `\let`, `\fututrelet` and a few others) at the very start of the run, and save all the definitions as we go.