# String equality in \ifx conditional using output from concatenating macros

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

Please consider the following MWE - where I try to test for string equality between an parameter, and a test string prepared by a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\testStr#1{IOIO#1}

\newcommand{\doTest}[1]{%
\edef\tmphwp{\testStr{XX}} %
\typeout{=\tmphwp=#1=} %
\ifx\tmphwp#1{%
\typeout{~equal}%
}\else{%
\typeout{!not equal}%
}\fi %
\typeout{ ^^J } % newline in terminal stdout
}

\begin{document}

\doTest{12}

\doTest{hello}

\doTest{IOIOXX}

\end{document}
```

Strangely, this seems to always determine strings are unequal - even if I enter specifically the right string - terminal log (from `pdflatex`) reports:

```
=IOIOXX=12=
!not equal


=IOIOXX=hello=
!not equal


=IOIOXX=IOIOXX=
!not equal
```

Hmm ... I would have expected `IOIOXX` = `IOIOXX` ?!

Can anyone explain why am I not getting the expected results - and how to get the right comparison? Does this have maybe to do anything with catcodes?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: You are doing `\ifx\tmphwp IOIOXX` which is of course false, because `\tmphwp` is a control sequence and `I` is a character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main thing to note is that `\ifx` compares, *without expanding them*, the two tokens that follow. Now let's slowly look at what  `\dotest{IOIOXX}` expands to.

1. `\edef\tmphwp{\testStr{XX}}` that's equivalent to `\def\tmphwp{IOIOXX}`
2. `\typeout{=\tmphwp=#1=}` that prints on the screen `=IOIOXX=IOIOXX=`
3. The conditional

   ```
   \ifx\tmphwp IOIOXX{%
     \typeout{~equal}%
   }\else{%
     \typeout{!not equal}%
   }\fi %
   \typeout{ ^^J } % newline in terminal stdout
   ```

which is false, because `\tmphwp` is different from `I`.

You're making a few other errors: your way of writing the code leaves a fair amount of spurious spaces; the true and the false branches of the conditional are *not* required to be in braces, which in most cases would even be wrong.

What to do in order to compare two strings? Put the one given as argument in the replacement test of a temporary macro:

```
\def\dotest#1{%
  \def\next{#1}%
  \ifx\tmphwp\next
    \typeout{EQUAL}%
  \else
    \typeout{NOT EQUAL}%
  \fi
}
```

where you already have set somewhere `\tmphwp` to expand to the "control string" (I don't see why you should set it when doing the test itself), say with

```
\def\tmphwp{IOIOXX}
```

Let's say that `\tmphwp` expands to `IOIOXX`: now `\ifx` will compare the two control sequences `\tmphwp` and `\next` which *are* equal, because they are both not `\long`, their parameter text is the same (empty) and they have the same replacement text (`IOIOXX`).

Conversely, `\dotest{AA}` would evaluate the test to false.

Comment: Many thanks for that @egreg - I managed to independently arrive at a solution [posted below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57168/2595); but I will accept your answer because of something I wasn't aware until now: "... \ifx compares, _without expanding them_, the two tokens ...". Many thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got this solved, thanks to [tex core - Detecting catcode in parameter text - TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9873/detecting-catcode-in-parameter-text); especially [this note from @HendrikVogt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9875/2595):

> This has nothing to do with catcodes of \fooA or \fooB. The \ifx test just sees that the parameter texts of the two macros are different (they contain different @s), so it turns out negative. The \ifx test doesn't care what the difference is.

... which means that, however, it *does* have to do with the catcodes of the characters of a "string content" of a "variable" (command)... and the `\detokenize` snippet by [@Jason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15346/2595) finally put this all in place.

One other problem I've frequently encountered, is that sometimes when I do, say `\detokenize{\command}` in an `\edef` and then try to `\typeout` the output - instead of the characters of the content, I see `\command` again (understood apparently as a single token). @Jason's use of \expandafter made me finally realize that such constructs should be written:

`\edef\tpmx{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\mycommand}}`

... the first `\expandafter` "escaping" the `\detokenize` - and the second one escaping the `{` curly brace - so that `\mycommand` can be expanded down to its content first; and `\detokenize` can subsequently work on the characters of the content (the variable value). (*note however that there is no need for such escaping when `\detokenize` works on `#1` - the stanza  `\edef\tmphwb{\detokenize{#1}}` seems to work just fine*)

So, in brief - it is about the catcodes (I guess); and once we have to compare strings that we expect should have the same (ASCII) content, but somehow ended up with differing catcodes (from say diverse macros) - then we can call `\detokenize` to "reset" the catcodes of characters of both strings before comparison - and then the `\ifx` comparison can be seen to work:

```
=IOIOXX=12=IOIOXX=12=
!not equal
!not equal
!not equal


=IOIOXX=hello=IOIOXX=hello=
!not equal
!not equal
!not equal


=IOIOXX=IOIOXX=IOIOXX=IOIOXX=
!not equal
!not equal
\~equal
```

The above `pdflatex` terminal output was produced with this modification of the OP MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\testStr#1{IOIO#1}

\newcommand{\doTest}[1]{%
\edef\tmphwp{\testStr{XX}} %
\edef\tmphwb{\detokenize{#1}} %
% \edef\tmphwc{\detokenize{\tmphwp}} % NO: outputs \tmphwp!
% to have \detokenize{\tmphwp} show
%  actual content as expected here,
%  MUST use two \expandafter's:
%   one to skip \detokenize, and other to skip the
%   brace; - so \tmphwp can be expanded first!
\edef\tmphwc{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\tmphwp}} %
\typeout{=\tmphwp=#1=\tmphwc=\tmphwb=} %
%
\ifx\tmphwp#1{%
  \typeout{\~equal}%
}\else{%
  \typeout{!not equal}%
}\fi %
%
\ifx\tmphwp\tmphwb{%
  \typeout{\~equal}%
}\else{%
  \typeout{!not equal}%
}\fi %
%
\ifx\tmphwc\tmphwb{%
  \typeout{\~equal}%
}\else{%
  \typeout{!not equal}%
}\fi %
\typeout{ ^^J } % newline in terminal stdout
}

\begin{document}

\doTest{12}

\doTest{hello}

\doTest{IOIOXX}

\end{document}
```

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: Category codes have nothing to do with the question as posed. Anyway, you're still making the same errors of considering the true and false branches as arguments in braces, which are *not*. You've been warned. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for that, @egreg - I am aware I am missing a lot of details, and it is very hard for me to get rid of the OOP type of thinking; which is why I try to come up with examples that sort of emulate that behavior, and still work :) Hopefully that will eventually lead me to understand the details better eventually; since unfortunately right now I cannot afford to get through the Tex book and other resources in detail. Thus, warning appreciated (I'll sure get back to it at a certain point) `:)` Cheers!

Comment: `\edef\x{\detokenize{\z}}` and `\edef\y{\detokenize\expandafter{\z}}` will result in *different* macros if, say, `\z` expands to `abc`. There's no need for an `\expandafter` before `\detokenize` in the second case.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that example, @egreg - it points well why I should be careful with the code in above posting; it will take me some time to understand that a little better, though... Cheers!