# How can i create multiple documents from one template - depending on special "variables"?

Tags: conditionals, automation

I am currently trying to set up a document template that allows for automated creation of different output files depending on a certain "input".
The "input" could be a variable or a certain kind of command.

What i am trying to achieve is something along the lines of

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tool}{Photoshop}

\begin{document}

\section{Install Guide for the tool \tool}

\ldots

After installation, you can find the tool under ``C:\textbackslash Program
Files\textbackslash\tool''. \par\bigskip

Pseudocode starts here: \par\bigskip

if (\textbackslash tool == ``Photoshop''): \newline

The amazing thing about \textbackslash tool\ is: it is quite
expensive\ldots\newline

fi\par\bigskip

else if (\textbackslash tool == ``GIMP''):  \newline

The amazing thing about \textbackslash tool is: it is freeware and
Open-Source as well!\newline

fi\par\bigskip

else: \newline

I don't know what tool you are talking about, please tell me more! 

\end{document}
```

So far, i have only found "if" examples comparing numbers with `\ifnum` or macros with `\ifx`.
This does not seem to work with strings, however. I am aware of the `includeonly` and `excludeonly`packages, which would however require a lot of fiddling once the document grows bigger.
Also, it would probably be difficult to steer `includeonly/excludeonly` from outside of the document (document build will be automatized via `ant`)

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29133/how-to-create-switch-structure-comparing-strings-in-latex - there you can find `\ifstrequal` from `etoolbox`. This can handle your string matching.

Comment: This has come up several times as TeX's idea of a comparison is somewhat different to many other languages, see for example [String equality in \ifx conditional using output from concatenating macros](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57159) or [String test, with complicated arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43601) for some background. These might help you.

Comment: For me it is not clear what you want to achieve. For string comparison the ifthen package could be used. You should avoid `includeonly` and the like in this context, since it has several side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `\ifcsname`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\newcommand{\tool}{Photoshop}
%\newcommand{\tool}{GIMP}
%\newcommand{\tool}{Libre Office}
\newcommand{\tool}{Invisibility cloak}
%
\newcommand{\defineTool}[2]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname [#1]\endcsname{%
The amazing thing about #1 is: #2\newline}}
%
\newcommand{\toolInfo}[1]{%
\ifcsname [#1]\endcsname
\csname [#1]\endcsname
\else
``#1'', really? I don't know what tool you are talking about, please tell me more! 
\fi
}
%
\defineTool{Photoshop}{it is quite expensive\ldots}
\defineTool{GIMP}{it is freeware and Open-Source as well!}
\defineTool{Libre Office}{%
it is the free power-packed open source personal productivity suite 
for Windows, Macintosh and Linux.
}

\begin{document}
\section{Install Guide for the tool \tool}
\ldots
After installation, you can find the tool under ``C:\textbackslash Program
Files\textbackslash\tool''. \par\bigskip

\toolInfo{\tool}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate a bit on the `\definetool` part? Especially, why is `\expandafter`necessary?

Comment: @Fabian Schmidt: Here `\expandafter` is necessary, because
it instructs TeX to prepare a command name to be defined (e.g. `[GIMP]`,
which can be used directly as `\csname[GIMP]\endcsname` as a `\newcommand`.
Without `\expandafter` a command name would be considered as just `csname`.

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to accomplish a similar task, I used the package: [xstring](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring/).

The documentation is here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf